# Browserify with Angular and non-CommonJS libraries

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, browserify, commonjs

I am trying to convert my Angular project to use CommonJS and Browserify. My issue though is that some of my Angular modules are not in the CommonJS format. What is the best way to include them?

For example, in my app-js, I have:

```
angular
    .module('app', ['ngRoute', 'ngResource', 'ngCookies', 'ngSanitize',
                    'ngMessages', 'flash', 'smart-table', 'ui.bootstrap',
                    'isteven-multi-select'])
```

So for most of these, I can just get the npm version and add a `var ngRoute = require(ng-route)`, etc. Some of the modules, like 'isteven-multi-select' do not have a CommonJS version. How can I include that in my code?

Answer (score 0):

### How to make them commonJs:

add this in your file :

```
require('./isteven-multi-select');
```

and create isteven-multi-select.js file in same directory (you can change directory but then in `require` change path).

now in **isteven-multi-select.js** add at the top:

```
module.exports = angular.module('isteven-multi-select',[])
//rest of the code, for example
.service('someservice', function () {...})
.controller('somecontroller', function() {...})
```

Comment: I'd rather do it without changing the library so I don't have to go through this process every time the library is updated.

Comment: is this library yours? if yes, then you can add to it package.json and make it to be npm package (you will not have to change library file). You can use it as normal javascript file or as npm package. If this solution corresponds to you, write a comment, and I will edit answer and write in details how to achieve it

Comment: It is not my library.